# UIButton Title not showing inside UIStackView

Tags: swift, uibutton, uistackview

I created a `UIStackView` with a `UIImageView` and a `UIButton`. The text inside of the `UIButton` won't show. I can tell that `autolayout` works because the background and the selection of my `UIButton` both work properly.

The title always disappears when I have the constraints on. I set the `image` to `0/0/0/0` without margins and aligned the button to the image's edges.

[image]
[image]

Has anyone run into this or knows how to fix it?

Comment: mind sharing some screenshots?

Comment: added them to the post

Comment: I've come up against the same problem when placing a UIButton inside a UIStackView programmatically. There the solution is to set the text colour using .setTitleColor(). So you could either try setting the colour of the button so that it isn't simply "default" in Interface Builder or you could set the colour programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I simply used a UIView. I don't know what made me use the UIStackView but I guess it's not made for overlaying objects.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11253132)

Comment: Yes it does because the stackview is not designed to have an element on top of others as far as I understand. That's why using uiview is the answer to the problem

Comment: @Stefan How does this not attempt to provide an answer? It might be completely wrong, [but that doesn't mean we should abuse the review queues to delete it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664)